# JQuery how to run script on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm doing is making a theme with two layouts, which are changeable by button press, from standard blog layout to a gallery layout etc.

However I wan't to run the infinite scroll script when the button is pressed for the gallery layout, everything works except for infinite scroll.

How can I run another script along with this? Kinda like taking away the `<!-- / -->` around a script to activate it, if you know what I mean.

```
$("a.button").toggle(function() {
        $(this).addClass("toggle");
        $("div.posts").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).fadeIn("fast").addClass("gallery");
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("toggle");
        $("div.posts").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).fadeIn("fast").removeClass("gallery");
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: did you get infinite scroll to work without this layout switch

Comment: @Beygi Yes infinite scroll works fine, however it's already active on the page (despite which layout is used), so it's calling for all blog posts in both layouts, I want pagination on first layout, infinite scroll on second. I need to somehow have a separate script run when a link is clicked (which is attached to layout changer)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you initialize both layouts on page load (DOM Ready) and just toggle them via CSS `display` property. The main reason for that is that you wouldn't need to re-initialize the infinite scroll object each time, and destroy it when user toggles back to blog style.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `<a>` tag then you have to use:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    ... scroll code...
});
```

and if you want to access it by an ID then use like this:

```
   $('#anyId').click(function(){
    ... scroll code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.gallery').click(function(){
    ... scroll code...
});
```

Adding a click listener just to the gallery class.  Will that work?

Comment: Trying this now, but what will happen if the layout is switched back again to default? Infinite scroll will still be there, I think.

Comment: Would there be a way to dump infinite scroll if the layout switch is clicked while in gallery view? Another listener, but something to dump.

Comment: sorry for the long wait, i was afk.  Ya you can easily do a listener for the reverse as well.  Just put the kill switch for it right after your removeclass for gallery.